# Unlink Geometry Dash Acc. Email

Tags: geometry-dash

I have an old GD account that I don't use anymore. I tried to create another one but my main email was used on the old account. I've tried the support email (support@robtopgames.com) and I'm not expecting results from that. I've tried the fix email link on the Boomlings website and it doesn't work. I've tried anything you'd normally think of and can't find a fix. Is there a way to unlink my account? Or even better, use an email for the 2 accounts?